# Ceph rgw LDAP authorization

Tags: ceph, radosgw

I trying setup LDAP(Active Directory) authetication ceph rgw. 
My ceph version 12.2.2. 
My config file ceph.conf

```
[cephrgwhost]
rgw_frontends = civetweb port=443
rgw_ldap_uri = "ldap://adceph.ceph.int:389"
rgw_ldap_binddn = "CN=cephldap,CN=Users,DC=ceph,DC=int"
rgw_ldap_secret = "Password"
rgw_ldap_searchdn = "cn=users,dc=ceph,dc=int"
rgw_ldap_dnattr = "cn"
rgw_s3_auth_use_ldap = true
debug rgw = 20
```

At rgw host i make three commands

```
# export RGW_ACCESS_KEY_ID="<username>"
# export RGW_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="<password>"
# radosgw-token --encode --ttype=ad
```

the result of these commands is the base64 string:

```
ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo=
```

in the decoded state the string looks like this. Login and password are in this line

```
{
    "RGW_TOKEN": {
        "version": 1,
        "type": "ad",
        "id": "cephldap",
        "key": "password"
    }
}
```

for connection to rgw i use python boto. I not understund what use need value for variable aws_secret_access_key

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
access_key = 'base64'
secret_key = ''

    conn = boto.connect_s3(
            aws_access_key_id = access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
            host = 'cephrgwhost',
            port = 7480,
            is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
            calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
            )

    for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
            print bucket
            print "{name}\t{created}".format(
                    name = bucket.name,
                    created = bucket.creation_date,
            )
```

execution of the script gives this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3python.py", line 18, in <module>
    for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py", line 447, in get_a
ll_buckets
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><RequestId
>tx000000000000000000004-005b7e7f94-1ebb3-default</RequestId><HostId>1ebb3-defau
lt-default</HostId></Error>
```

the contents of the cephrgwhost log (log file /var/log/ceph/ceph-client.rgw.cephrgwhost.log). I'm looking at the traffic between cephrgwhost and adceph.ceph.int, no ldap traffic is present

```
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424061 7fa4d427c700 20 CONTENT_LENGTH=0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424099 7fa4d427c700 20 HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=identity
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424104 7fa4d427c700 20 HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=AWS ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo=:CRW41WihDir6Xj6cJihdMKj95/M=
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424109 7fa4d427c700 20 HTTP_DATE=Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:20:20 GMT
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424111 7fa4d427c700 20 HTTP_HOST=ceph132v12.ceph.int:7480
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424123 7fa4d427c700 20 HTTP_USER_AGENT=Boto/2.49.0 Python/2.7.10 Windows/7
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424131 7fa4d427c700 20 REQUEST_METHOD=GET
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424133 7fa4d427c700 20 REQUEST_URI=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424134 7fa4d427c700 20 SCRIPT_URI=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424136 7fa4d427c700 20 SERVER_PORT=7480
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424139 7fa4d427c700  1 ====== starting new request req=0x7fa4d42761f0 =====
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424190 7fa4d427c700  2 req 9:0.000041::GET /::initializing for trans_id = tx000000000000000000009-005b7ea68a-1ebb3-default
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424202 7fa4d427c700 10 rgw api priority: s3=5 s3website=4
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424204 7fa4d427c700 10 host=ceph132v12.ceph.int
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424211 7fa4d427c700 20 subdomain= domain= in_hosted_domain=0 in_hosted_domain_s3website=0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424215 7fa4d427c700 20 final domain/bucket subdomain= domain= in_hosted_domain=0 in_hosted_domain_s3website=0 s->info.domain= s->info.request_uri=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424264 7fa4d427c700 20 get_handler handler=26RGWHandler_REST_Service_S3
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424270 7fa4d427c700 10 handler=26RGWHandler_REST_Service_S3
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424272 7fa4d427c700  2 req 9:0.000134:s3:GET /::getting op 0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424280 7fa4d427c700 10 op=26RGWListBuckets_ObjStore_S3
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424282 7fa4d427c700  2 req 9:0.000144:s3:GET /:list_buckets:verifying requester
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424289 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::StrategyRegistry::s3_main_strategy_t: trying rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424292 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::S3AnonymousEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424296 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::S3AnonymousEngine denied with reason=-1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424304 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424306 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::LDAPEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424332 7fa4d427c700 10 get_canon_resource(): dest=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.424335 7fa4d427c700 10 string_to_sign:
GET


Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:20:20 GMT
/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.425295 7fa4d427c700 12 auth search filter: (cn=cephldap)
2018-08-23 15:20:26.426999 7fa4d427c700  5 auth ldap_search_s error uid=cephldap ldap err=1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442038 7fa4d427c700  5 auth ldap_search_s error uid=cephldap ldap err=1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442066 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::LDAPEngine denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442071 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442073 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::LocalEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442100 7fa4d427c700 10 get_canon_resource(): dest=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442103 7fa4d427c700 10 string_to_sign:
GET


Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:20:20 GMT
/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442164 7fa4d427c700 20 get_system_obj_state: rctx=0x7fa4d4273ac0 obj=default.rgw.meta:users.keys:ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= state=0x5563c351ef60 s->prefetch_data=0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.442182 7fa4d427c700 10 cache get: name=default.rgw.meta+users.keys+ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= : type miss (requested=0x6, cached=0x0)
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444163 7fa4d427c700 10 moving default.rgw.meta+users.keys+ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= to cache LRU end
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444182 7fa4d427c700  5 error reading user info, uid=ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= can't authenticate
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444186 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::LocalEngine denied with reason=-2028
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444189 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444191 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::StrategyRegistry::s3_main_strategy_t: trying rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444194 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::S3AnonymousEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444198 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::S3AnonymousEngine denied with reason=-1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444200 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444202 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::LDAPEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444223 7fa4d427c700 10 get_canon_resource(): dest=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444225 7fa4d427c700 10 string_to_sign:
GET


Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:20:20 GMT
/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.444630 7fa4d427c700 12 auth search filter: (cn=cephldap)
2018-08-23 15:20:26.445286 7fa4d427c700  5 auth ldap_search_s error uid=cephldap ldap err=1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455836 7fa4d427c700  5 auth ldap_search_s error uid=cephldap ldap err=1
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455864 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::LDAPEngine denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455869 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSv2ExternalAuthStrategy denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455871 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy: trying rgw::auth::s3::LocalEngine
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455894 7fa4d427c700 10 get_canon_resource(): dest=/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455898 7fa4d427c700 10 string_to_sign:
GET


Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:20:20 GMT
/
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455909 7fa4d427c700 20 get_system_obj_state: rctx=0x7fa4d4273ac0 obj=default.rgw.meta:users.keys:ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= state=0x5563c351ef60 s->prefetch_data=0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.455918 7fa4d427c700 10 cache get: name=default.rgw.meta+users.keys+ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= : type miss (requested=0x6, cached=0x0)
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457111 7fa4d427c700 10 cache put: name=default.rgw.meta+users.keys+ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= info.flags=0x0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457120 7fa4d427c700 10 moving default.rgw.meta+users.keys+ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= to cache LRU end
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457138 7fa4d427c700  5 error reading user info, uid=ewogICAgIlJHV19UT0tFTiI6IHsKICAgICAgICAidmVyc2lvbiI6IDEsCiAgICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiYWQiLAogICAgICAgICJpZCI6ICJjZXBobGRhcCIsCiAgICAgICAgImtleSI6ICJwYXNzd29yZCIKICAgIH0KfQo= can't authenticate
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457154 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::LocalEngine denied with reason=-2028
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457159 7fa4d427c700 20 rgw::auth::s3::AWSAuthStrategy denied with reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457161 7fa4d427c700  5 Failed the auth strategy, reason=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457163 7fa4d427c700 10 failed to authorize request
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457165 7fa4d427c700 20 handler->ERRORHANDLER: err_no=-13 new_err_no=-13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457300 7fa4d427c700  2 req 9:0.033161:s3:GET /:list_buckets:op status=0
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457307 7fa4d427c700  2 req 9:0.033169:s3:GET /:list_buckets:http status=403
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457312 7fa4d427c700  1 ====== req done req=0x7fa4d42761f0 op status=0 http_status=403 ======
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457326 7fa4d427c700 20 process_request() returned -13
2018-08-23 15:20:26.457411 7fa4d427c700  1 civetweb: 0x5563c3739000: 10.201.0.131 - - [23/Aug/2018:15:20:26 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 1 0 - Boto/2.49.0 Python/2.7.10 Windows/7
2018-08-23 15:20:30.973550 7fa4f48d7700  2 RGWDataChangesLog::ChangesRenewThread: start
```

Answer (score 0):

In the logs the following line indicates 
`5 auth ldap_search_s error uid=cephldap ldap err=1`
That it tried to contact ldap and returned that error, are you sure the ldap config settings in ceph.conf ie. binddn and searchdn are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i sure the ldap config correct. I  moved rgw_ldap_(settings) to [global] section in config file ceph.conf and remov in string rgw_ldap_uri = "ldap://adceph.ceph.int:389" port ":389" and change rgw_ldap_secret = "Password" on rgw_ldap_secret = /path/to/pass and authentication began to work.